# Rearrange order of related -common fields in Dynamics 365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am quite new to Dynamics 365 world so please don't be harsh. I have been asked to rearrange the order of the `Related - Common` options and bring the `Connections` option to the top just below the documents.

[image]

I have gone to customize the `solution->main form-> selected` `Relationships` and moved it underneath `documents-> save->publish customizations`. But when I refresh the page nothing changes and still show the `Connections` option at bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are editing the left navigation of the same form in form editor what you are looking at from UI.

Many times, UCI app will be having a form added as asset/artifact (lets say "Information Form") and we may be editing the different form (for ex. "Sales Form") and publishing. Make sure this is not the case.